# Why doesn't C++ allow :: on objects of known types?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > vi;

    // This is legal.
    for( std::vector< int >::iterator it = vi.begin(); it != vi.end(); ++it )
    {
    }

    // This is not legal. WHY NOT? 
    // Compiler knows vi's type, as evident from the c++11 syntax for such loop:
    // for( auto it : each vi )
    // So why not support :: on objects of known type?
    for( vi::iterator it = vi.begin(); it != vi.end(); ++it )
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/3002139).

Comment: @BaummitAugen I want to give you points for just linking that.

Comment: @Barry You would have to wait at least two minutes, I'm maxed for today. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Because `vi` is a variable, not a type, and `::` can only be applied to a type or a namespace.  If you want to get the type so you can use `::`, use `decltype`:

```
for( decltype(vi)::iterator it = vi.begin(); it != vi.end(); ++it )
```

As java shows, `::` is actually complete unnecessary -- the language could have use `.` instead, as context is always enough to tell what is going on.  Whether that makes for a better or worse language is entirely subjective.

Comment: You can use decltype and not typeof(vi) because typeof is determined at runtime. PERIOD!

Comment: @JeremyConterio No. You can use `decltype`. Period.

Comment: The question seems to be about why `operator::` was not defined to work on objects too, not how to work around that restriction.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It merely re-affirms the premise of the question. (Sadly, there is no answer other than "because".)

Comment: I am not asking *whether* C++ disallows that or *how to work around* that limitation. I'm curious *why* C++ designers disallowed such syntax, As evident by your proposed `decltype(vi)::` workaround the `vi::` syntax would by unambiguous as well. So why not allow that?

Comment: "*`::` can only be applied to a type*" -- or to a namespace.

Answer (score 3):

It could be done, by making `variable::x` equivalent to `decltype(variable)::x` in some cases.

It simply was not.

There is no "reason" for it.

Sorry not to be more helpful.

Feel free to suggest it to the committee, on [the `std-discussion` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-discussion)!

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't it? Here's a few ideas:

1. There is no authoritative answer. [Read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio/323382#323382).
2. Nobody's proposed such a thing. [Have at it](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal).
3. In every context in which you have a variable, you already have the type of that variable, so you could always just use the type anyway.
4. `::` is called the scope resolution operator. Classes have scope. Namespaces have scope. Variables do not have scope.
5. There's already a reasonable workaround. Can't do `vi::iterator` but you can do `decltype(vi)::iterator` so why clutter the language?

Comment: "looks wrong to me" is hardly a reason, bro

Comment: You think that `decltype(vi)::iterator` is less cluttering that `vi::iterator`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Alright, I'll stick to the real ones.

Comment: @Michael I said clutter the *language*. Also `vi::iterator` is clearly more cluttering than `auto`, so...

Comment: #4 is a bit of a cop-out, since there were 13 years between the language's existence (decades more if you count pre-standardisation) and the introduction of `decltype`. But whatever, I'll allow it...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is a reason I hear from time to time. "Why do we need language feature X when language feature Y accomplishes the same thing?" Obviously I cannot authoritatively answer "why" - and it's a poor question nevertheless.